# Command "yarn create react-app ." doesn't work without root permission (Ubuntu 20)

Tags: reactjs, linux, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg

Can't install react without root permssion it always gives error:

"Cannot create "/usr/local/bin/create-react-app" due to insufficient permissions.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command."

Tried to install react app via yarn on Linux system (Ubuntu 20)

Comment: Have you tried with sudo yarn create react-app? May the reason is that yarn is install for super user only. It might be helpful if you reinstall the nodejs.

Comment: Why do you try to create an app in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Actually I didn't, I just installed yarn globally via npm and runned script on folder I created in Desktop